# On lyrics of a Big Joe Turner song

Tags: blues

Im trying to understand what is Big Joe Turner saying on *blues on central avenue* from 0:50 to 1:15. Here is the link:

http://youtu.be/kOhxZ78p-rE

This is what I hear:

> never had so much **** anywhere in my life, never had (so much for you honey?) anywhere in my life, till I fell in love with you and found out you was somebody's else wife.

The parts in **** and in parentheses I cannot really understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A google search for *"till I fell in love with you" "honey anywhere in my life"* reveals a result at ch.ucpress.edu/content/ucpch/82/3/48.full.pdf -

> Never had so much sport, babe, anywhere in my life.
>
> Never had so much sport, honey, anywhere in my life.

Comment: This sounds right to me both by ear and for the meaning.  He's saying it was all just a real good time for him, until he both fell in love and also found out that his girlfriend is already married.

Comment: @ChrisSunami though surely the point when you find that your girl is already married is when the 'sport' starts for real :)